# Playing YouTubePlayer Sound in Background Swift

Tags: ios, swift, youtube-api, ytplayerview

I'm using the YouTubeSDK to play YouTube videos in my app found here: https://github.com/gilesvangruisen/Swift-YouTube-Player

However, when the user presses home I want the sound to keep playing in the background. 
https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper/issues/38

I'm currently trying this in the `App Delegate` (awful conversion) in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
let sessionEror:NSError?
do {

    let playBG = try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, withOptions: .DefaultToSpeaker)

} catch let error as NSError  {
    print("ERROR")
}
```

And this is in it's own function in the same file:

```
func playerView(YTPlayerView: YTPlayerState, didChangeToState: YTPlayerState) {

        switch {

        case YTPlayerState.Paused:
            YTPlayerState.Playing,
        break
        }


    }
```

Any idea how to keep playing the sound in the background using the YouTube SDK? Also, is it possible to just play the sound in the background and **not** the video?

Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separating out the video and audio of a Youtube video is against [YouTube Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms). Look under Prohibitions

> 8. separate, isolate, or modify the audio or video components of any YouTube audiovisual content made available through the YouTube API;
> 9. promote separately the audio or video components of any YouTube audiovisual content made available through the YouTube API;

That being said, the workaround still remains the same as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20063630/play-audio-from-a-music-video-using-youtube-api-in-android-when-my-app-is-minim) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19294933/how-do-i-prevent-youtube-stop-playback-using-android-api) which both suggest that you need to have a service that delegates the video's playback. Directly, the Youtube API will not allow you to do so.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. It's unfortunate YouTube hasn't broken down their API for music/sound separate from the videos. I'll definitely check those links out. This helps a lot. Thanks once again!