# Play YouTube Video´s Audio in Swift iOS App

Tags: ios, swift, youtube, youtube-api

First of all, I would like to say I know that doing that goes against YouTube R&Rs but this app is just for educational purposes.

So far I have used YoutubeInMp3 API, but I found out that that API fails a lot by returning the website to download the video(HTML) instead of the JSON containing the link to download the .mp3 video. Apart that they restrict the download speed to a low one which causes lots of problems when playing it.

I am seeking for ideas on how to do it, using another API or a library.

Thank you in advanced!

PS: I would´t mind getting an answer in Objective-C, but I prefer Swift.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this [thread](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper/issues/38) might give you an idea which is I think somewhat familiar to your issue.

> Go to Appdelegete.m file and add those lines on the function
>
> ```
> - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
>
> NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
> [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: &setCategoryError];
> ```

Be also noted of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34096713/5832311).  Since separating out the video and audio of a Youtube video is against [YouTube Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms). Given workaround is you need to have a service that delegates the video's playback.

Comment: I finally fixed it creating my own API. But thanks anyway very appreciated!